# Making os.Stat throw error such that IsNotExist returns false

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm trying to test the following branch:

```
if _, err := os.Stat(path); err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            continue
        }
        return errors.File().AddDetails(err)
    }
```

Obviously, `os.Stat` is going to throw an error if `path` doesn't exist. [Reading the Golang documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat) returns no details about the errors that `os.Stat` could return. Is there way to have `os.Stat` throw another kind of error?

Comment: Try to stat a path that you don't have permission to access the containing directory.

Comment: How do you do that from the unit testing environment though

Comment: The error codes handled in *nix environments are EAGAIN, EINVAL, and ENOENT: https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go#L139

Comment: OK, now how do you **cause** those errors (except the last one, which is obviously "file not found")? That is the question.

Comment: That depends on your unit testing environment. But there's plenty of stuff you should have no access to, for instance anything under `/root`. Try stating `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` as non-root you should get a nice error which isn't `IsNotExist()`. The error you get back from that is `&os.PathError{Op:"stat", Path:"/root/.ssh/authorized_keys", Err:0xd}` or as a string `stat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys: permission denied`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find it very difficult to control what errors are thrown and when by `os.Stat` in a platform independent way from a unit test. If you really need a test for the path where an unknown error type is returned, your best bet might be to refactor your package code so that you can mock `os.Stat`. Although you can't change the behavior of `os.Stat` directly, by taking advantage of the fact that Go has first-class functions, you can use a bit of indirection to mock it with very minimal changes to your code. If your package code looks like this:

```
package mypackage

import "os"

...

    if _, err := os.Stat(path); err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
           continue
        }
        return errors.File().AddDetails(err)
    }

...
```

Try refactoring it to use a non-exported package-scope function variable which is assigned `os.Stat`:

```
package mypackage

import "os"

var osStat = os.Stat

...

    if _, err := osStat(path); err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
           continue
        }
        return errors.File().AddDetails(err)
    }

...
```

Now, in your test code (which should be in the same package as the code under test), you can reassign `osStat` to any function with the same signature in order to mock it:

```
package mypackage

import (
        "os"
        "testing"
)

func TestNotExistError(t *testing.T) {
    osStat = func(string) (os.FileInfo, error) {
        return nil, os.ErrNotExist
    }
    // in case other test functions depend on the unmocked behavior
    defer func() {
        osStat = os.Stat
    }()

    // rest of the test which triggers the codepath above
}

func TestOtherError(t *testing.T) {
    osStat = func(string) (os.FileInfo, error) {
        return nil, os.ErrInvalid
    }
    // in case other test functions depend on the unmocked behavior
    defer func() {
        osStat = os.Stat
    }()

    // rest of the test which triggers the codepath above
}

...
```

Comment: nice trick, but it won’t work with the Stat() method of *os.File. One need a boolean `testError` which is set to false by default. The test is changed into  `if _, err := osStat(path); err != nil || testError {` and the boolean is set to true in the test function when we want the test to be true.

Answer (score 3):

You can cause an error such that `IsNotExist` returns false by passing an invalid filename.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    _, err := os.Stat("\000x")
    fmt.Println(err)

    // prints:
    // 
    // stat x: invalid argument
}
```

`\000 (ASCII: NUL)` is an invalid character in unix file names.